# undefined JSON object / Array Javascript

Tags: arrays, json, stringify

**JSON Data**

`myData = {"data":[{"pre":1,"post":2}]}`

JSON.stringify(myData) shows that data is an array with one element, an object.

```
console.log("type of data: " + typeof(myData));
console.log("data: " + JSON.stringify(myData));
console.log("data.pre: " + data.pre);
```

**Log result**

```
type of data: object
data: {"data":[{"pre":1,"post":2}]}
data.pre: undefined
```

---

**I manually adjusted and added a JSON.**

It works with this JSON (without the object)

```
myData = {"pre":1,"post":2}
```

and

```
console.log("data.pre: " + data.pre);
```

**Log result**

```
data.pre: 1
```

How can i achieve this? I want to use it later as a variable.

```
pre = data.pre;
post = data.post;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data inside an array you need to specify the index of the object you want to access ex: `data[0].pre`

```js
myData = {"data":[{"pre":1,"post":2}]}

console.log("type of data: " + typeof(myData));
console.log("type of data: " + typeof(myData.data));
console.log("data: " + JSON.stringify(myData.data));
console.log("data.pre: " + myData.data[0].pre);
console.log("data.post: " + myData.data[0].post);
```